# GUI Disappeared after uninstalling udev

Tags: dual-boot, udev, 19.04

So after updating to 19.04, I got some problems concerning some packages, especially `udev`. I guess it was a mistake, but I removed and re-installed `udev`. After that everything worked fine and I got no errors. Next time I try to boot into ubuntu (I have dual boot, but I don't think that's the problem) I got no GUI, only a terminal. I have tried reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` as I saw in other posts, but that didn't work because the internet doesn't work, even with an internet cable. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: When I once lost GUI (probably due to upgrading python to unsupported version) I was able to connect to my home wifi using one of the answers sugested in this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92799/connecting-to-wifi-network-through-command-line) Sadly, I dont remember which one exactly but it did not include nmcli nor nmtui. I only have this link bookmarked under name \*\*SOLUTION***. ( And as for your main problem I wasn't able to restored my GUI due to bunch of commands I used trying to get old python version)

Comment: Unfortunately I have already some of these and I couldn't connect with wifi.

Comment: Do you have wpa_supplicant? I think that was the one that worked in my case. And maybe find out if you need to change *wlan0* in commands to sth. else if you haven't already. I don't think I know how to help beyond that. Good luck!

Comment: What do you mean if I have wpa_supplicant?

Comment: You could boot from installation USB if you still have it, bind couple directrories via chroot and install that way. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

Comment: Unfortunately I don't currently have a USB with me and I am trying to solve it before I get one.

Comment: wpa_supplicant as it is sugested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158734/213902)

Comment: Have you solved the issue? If you still have it, run `ifconfig -a` to check you still have net interface detected.

Comment: Ended up reinstalling to save some time.

Answer (score 0):

Try running startx. This is the command to start the GUI. It will give you a log in Xorg's log file if it fails. Post that content for troubleshooting.

Comment: It failed. The error essage was 
xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/John/. Xauthority
xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/John/. Xauthority

/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc: 3: exec: /usr/bin/X: not found 
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused 
xinit: server error 
xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/John/. Xauthority

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be considered as an answer, but unfortunately I reinstalled Ubuntu.
Also I'd like to point out for the future BanAnanas's [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138163/gui-disappeared-after-uninstalling-udev?noredirect=1#comment1886948_1138163).